# Problem with punctuation and removal of post owner usernames on comments

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

I found out today that if you have a user’s name with an “@“ in a comment on that user’s post, it removes it. For example,

> @PostOwner Your post is very nice.

becomes

> Your post is very nice.

However, this works badly with punctuation. I posted a comment:

> @Voldemort’sWrath this is a test.

at the beginning on a post by that user, and it looked like this:

> ’sWrath this is a test.

**With users whose names contain apostrophes (and likely other punctuation), the automatic removal of their usernames from comments doesn’t work right.**

This bug does not occur with usernames with spaces.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this still happen if the username contains a straight apostrophe `'` instead of a smart one `’`?

Comment: It turns out that this is because I typed a smart quote, not a dumb quote.

Comment: @Glorfindel Just FYI, I did flag this asking for a [tag:status-bydesign] tag to be added; the mod/CM handling the flag opted to close this instead of adding the tag.

Comment: Oh, [bug] + [status-bydesign] would've worked for me as well. But I can't add that tag :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This is actually not a problem.

It turns out that the user’s name has a dumb quote `'`, not a smart quote `’`, but my phone typed a smart quote when I wrote the comment. Writing

> @Voldemort'sWrath with a dumb quote.

displays perfectly, as

> with a dumb quote.

Comment: Ahh, autocorrect...

Comment: @Sonic Blame iOS’s keyboard. The quote buttons are both smart by default.